# copy local files to aks premium or standard storage

Tags: kubernetes, azure-storage, azure-aks

I am new to k8s in azure (I have used k8s in a non-cloud server) and I dont find info on how can I copy local files/directories to aks's premium or standard storage.

[image]

This link [PVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/concepts-storage) shows how to create a PVC and how to mount it in a pod, but I cannot find how do I copy files from my local pc to aks's premium or standard storage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To copy files you can use [azcopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-files) for azure files and [azure storage explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/disks-use-storage-explorer-managed-disks) for azure managed disk.

Comment: Does the persisten volumne dissapear when I delete the cluster? So it is only persisten if I delete nodes in the cluster?

Comment: @user1571823 Yes. When you create a new *PVC* then it creates a *Disk* resource under the Kubernetes infrastructure (`MC_myResourceGroup_myAKSCluster_eastus`) resource group (RG). If you delete the Kubernetes cluster then the infrastructure RG will also be delete hence the persistent volume, the *Disk* as well.